# Google Maps: Want to drag the map directly after setting draggable to true

Tags: javascript, google-maps

To avoid unwanted scrolling in small browser-windows, I set `draggable` option of my Google Map to false:

```
if (document.getElementById('map').offsetWidth < 350 )
   map.setOptions({
      draggable: false,
      scrollwheel: false
   });
```

Then, I add a timer/function which enables dragging after one second of mousedown if a user wants it (sort of longpress):

```
var timer = null;

function draggable_true() {
   map.setOptions({
      draggable: true,
      scrollwheel: true
   });
}

var mdown = google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'mousedown', function() {        
   timer = setTimeout( draggable_true, 1000 );
});

var mup = google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'mouseup', function() {
   clearTimeout( timer );
});
```

This works fine, after one second the cursor changes to the hand-symbol. But to drag the map, I have to release the mousebutton once and press it again. So now I'm wondering how to drag the map directly (the mousebutton is already and still down).

I tried MouseEvent inside the `draggable_true()` function to simulate another mousedown, but it doesn't work:

```
var event = new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
   'view': window,
   'bubbles': true,
   'cancelable': true
});              

document.getElementById('map').dispatchEvent(event);
```

I also tried mouseup first and then mousedown, but also no result (not even mistakes or warnings).

So any ideas anybody? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem using jQuery-Mobile's [taphold event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/), as this event allows you to detect a longpress and then bind the mousemove event to your drag function. When the user releases the mouse, you unbind the mousemove event and everything returns back to normal. Please, be aware that I didn't use this technique with GoogleMaps but it should work nonetheless.